# Transition Animation is not working Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to navigate from one view controller to other using tap gesture navigation. I want add transition animation into it. I tried with two ways but it didn't worked for me. -

First approach :

```
               UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { ()-> Void in

                            let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                            let myTabBarController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
                            var appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                            appDel.window?.rootViewController = myTabBarController

                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
```

Second approach :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
               delay: 0.0,
               options: [.curveEaseIn],
               animations: {


    let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainMenuViewController") as! MainMenuViewController

    self.addChild(controller)
    self.view.addSubview(controller.view)
    controller.didMove(toParent: self)

}, completion: nil)
```

Can anybody please tell me whats the solution ?

Comment: do you want to push or present the `Viewcontroller` ?

Comment: and what transition you trying to achieve ? please explain it

Comment: Yes I want to push and present and pop view controller programmatically. A simple Smooth transition from one view controller to other.

Comment: Try => self.presentViewController(myTabBarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
Like in your first example but outside the UIView.animate closure. Only keep the let storyboard + let myTabBarController lines + the one before.

Comment: Thanks its presenting smoothly now. while closing I am using this self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)  @108g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to present

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

If you present a `ViewController` then you can only Dismiss it, It can be done by below code

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

To push

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated:true)
```

If you push a `ViewController` then you can only Pop it, It can be done by below code

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then after presenting ( self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil) ) how to get back from it [Pop from controller] @Vicky_Vignesh

Comment: @TejasRatunawar I have updated the code , please check !

Comment: Thats great! Thanks @Vicky_Vignesh

Comment: Hi, while presenting the view controller is loading from bottom side. I want that it will load from right hand side. How could we achieve that? @Vicky_Vignesh

Comment: @TejasRatunawar present and dismiss is like animating viewcontroller from bottom to up.
push and pop is like animation viewcontroller from right to left..
In this case you need to use push !

Comment: As per you provided Push code. It's not navigating. @Vicky_Vignesh I have added this code when button clicked -   let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainMenuViewController") as! MainMenuViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated:true)